# Android Java How to jump to a certain line

Tags: java, android

I want to skip the return if (firstAns.getText() != null) but there is no goto in java.

Please help and be simple.

Thanks!!!

```
EditText firstAns = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_ans);

    if (firstAns.getText() != null) {
        //I want to skip the return or jump down below it
    }
    return;
```

Comment: Even if you could use goto, you should never use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip the return like that, then I assume you want to return when `firstAns.getText() == null`

```
EditText firstAns = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_ans);

if (firstAns.getText() == null) return;

// rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method:

EditText firstAns = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_ans);

```
if (firstAns.getText() != null) {
    //I want to skip the return or jump down below it
    methodYouWant();
}
```

If the text is not null you will execute what is in the method, if is null you will do nothing

or you can do something like :

```
    if (firstAns.getText() != null) {
        //I want to skip the return or jump down below it
    }else{
     return;
    }
```

Comment: In this case the return will execute no matter what

Comment: Or just get rid of the != and make it == with the return.  Pretty straightforward.

Comment: but the code I have written is already in method. Can I use nested methods!?

Comment: @LikeWhiteOnRice yes right! the else will be usefull only if need to do something before the return!

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz Of course you can call a method in a method in a method... if not it will be limited